# How to export collection to TSV in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongoexport

How to export  the specfic filed in MongoDB to TSV format. 
I already try following query but I didn't get answer.

Query :

```
./mongoexport --port ***** -d "dbName" -c "collectionName" --csv --filed separator \t --fields fieldName1,fieldName2,field.fieldName3 --out file.csv
```

Comment: Is your mongo version > 3.0? From https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/ see - 
Changed in version 3.0.0: mongoexport removed the --csv option. Use the --type=csv option to specify CSV format for the output.

Comment: My mongodb version is 2.6.7. How to export the mongodb in tsv format.